# How to make a shortcut on my desktop of a file which is located in a dropbox?

Tags: command-line, shortcuts

Title is pretty straightforward, how can I make a shortcut on my desktop of a file which is located in a cloud application? Dropbox in this case.

CLI method preffered as I would like to learn Linux.

EDITED: Distro - Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 0):

In 18.04 click on the Dropbox icon on the top bar and open the Dropbox folder and look for the file you want to place on your desktop.

Having found the file, right click on it and select Copy to... from the drop down menu.

Next step, you will be presented with a dialogue box to indicate where the file is to copied to. Select Desktop

[image]

The file will then be added to your desktop as directed.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to do the same using CLI?

Answer (score 0):

The question How put I a shortcut on my desktop is different then the solution is offered. This is copying a file to the desktop.

I found that making a real shortcut is possible:

Her is the contents of the file:

> [Desktop Entry] Version=1.0 Name=Adressen Comment=Geert
>   Exec=libreoffice --calc %U "/home/geertadmin/00_Documenten_WD/"00
>   Geert Adressen v9.xlsx"
>
> Icon=/usr/share/gnome-software/featured-chess.png
>
> Type=Application Categories=Utility Name[nl]=Geert adressen.dtp

Copy the contents with a texteditor in a file.
     Name the file: for example  Geert.adressen.dtp.desktop
     Save it on your Desktop
     Go to Properties of the file and make it executable (tab rights)

If you doubleclick it, there will be asked if it is to trusty. Yes.
and there is your real shortcut.

Remarks: it is the same kind of files in usr/share/applications/ named .desktop
You can find there the other applicationsparameters.

I found it by trying and error and do not exactly how it works.

Good luck with it!
Geert